# Why is a Dictionary collection that is not being iterated thru being treated as read-only?

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, html-parsing, key-value

I am trying to parse the contents of an HTML table with the following code.  My issue appears when I try to update the element in the rowVals collection: it tells me that the value is read-only.

Some rows span multiple columns so I want to make sure I map the cell values to the appropriate column when I parse the table.

I know when collections are being iterated thru, it chokes when you try to update that collection.  Since I am not iterating thru the rowVals collection, but rather another collection, I do not understand why my code is choking when I try to to set the value of a specific KVP element in rowVals.  Can anyone suggest a way to accomplish setting the appropriate value without having to add/remove existing KVPs?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filePath);

        var root = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().First(t => t.Name == "body");
        var tables = root.Descendants().Where(t => t.Name == "table");
        var trs = tables.First().Elements("tr");
        //parse the headers
        var headers = trs.First().Elements("th").Select(t => t.InnerText);

        //parse the column values
        var cells = trs.Skip(1).Select(tr => tr.Elements("td"));


        //update the column values for each row
        foreach (var item in cells)
        {
            int x = 0;

            var rowVals = headers.ToDictionary(t => t, t=>"");

            foreach (var item2 in item)
            {
                rowVals.ElementAt(x).Value = item2.InnerText;


                if (item2.Attributes.Any(t => t.Name == "colspan"))
                {
                    x = x + int.Parse(item2.Attributes.First(t => t.Name == "colspan").Value) - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    x++;
                }
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can never set the value of a `KeyValuePair` because [the property is read only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224761(v=vs.110).aspx) to begin with. This problem has nothing to do with collection iteration.

Second, dictionaries make no guarantee about the order of the items, so using `.ElementAt()` makes no sense anyways.